# How do I get only directories using Get-ChildItem?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm using PowerShell 2.0 and I want to pipe out all the subdirectories of a certain path. The following command outputs all files and directories, but I can't figure out how to filter out the files.

```
Get-ChildItem c:\mypath -Recurse
```

I've tried using `$_.Attributes` to get the attributes but then I don't know how to construct a literal instance of `System.IO.FileAttributes` to compare it to. In `cmd.exe` it would be

```
dir /b /ad /s
```

Answer (score 378, accepted):

**For PowerShell 3.0 and greater:**

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory
```

You can also use the aliases `dir`, `ls`, and `gci`

---

**For PowerShell versions less than 3.0:**

The `FileInfo` object returned by `Get-ChildItem` has a "base" property, `PSIsContainer`. You want to select only those items.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }
```

If you want the raw string names of the directories, you can do

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object FullName
```

Comment: Wish that was aliased to "IsFolder".

Comment: xcud: Not every hierarchy represented by a PSDrive is folder-based.

Comment: The semantic gap between "container" and "folder" is not one you can drive a truck through.

Comment: @xcud: See iraSenthil's answer. -Directory and -File also works on Get-ChildItem. No need to use the PSIsContainer attribute directly.

Comment: (Get-ChildItem | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | Select Name).Name

Comment: @xcud Just make it one. `Update-TypeData -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -TypeName "System.IO.DirectoryInfo" -MemberType ScriptProperty -MemberName "IsFolder" -Value {return $this.PSIsContainer} -Force` (Don't really do this but if you really insisted on having it....it's an option)

Answer (score 213):

In PowerShell 3.0, it is simpler:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory #List only directories
Get-ChildItem -File #List only files
```

Comment: dir is an alias to Get-ChildItem

Comment: @crashmstr Are you sure? I checked on my PS4.0. For me, `dir` was aliased to `Get-ChildItem`, and the `-Directory` and `-File` options worked as described. I used commands `echo $PSVersionTable`, `help dir`, `dir -Directory` and `dir -File` to come up with this comment.

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: `ls` and `dir` are aliases of `Get-ChildItem` pick your poison

Answer (score 56):

Use

```
Get-ChildItem -dir #lists only directories
Get-ChildItem -file #lists only files
```

If you prefer aliases, use

```
ls -dir #lists only directories
ls -file #lists only files
```

or

```
dir -dir #lists only directories
dir -file #lists only files
```

To recurse subdirectories as well, add `-r` option.

```
ls -dir -r #lists only directories recursively
ls -file -r #lists only files recursively
```

Tested on PowerShell 4.0, PowerShell 5.0 (Windows 10), [PowerShell Core 6.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-core-6-0-generally-available-ga-and-supported/) (Windows 10, Mac, and Linux), and [PowerShell 7.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/announcing-powershell-7-0/) (Windows 10, Mac, and Linux).

**Note**: On PowerShell Core, symlinks are not followed when you specify the `-r` switch. To follow symlinks, specify the `-FollowSymlink` switch with `-r`.

**Note 2**: PowerShell is now cross-platform, since version 6.0. The cross-platform version was originally called PowerShell Core, but the the word "Core" has been dropped since PowerShell 7.0+.

Get-ChildItem documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem

Comment: This won't work in Powershell 2.0 which was the specific need of the OP.  the -[/Dir/Directory] are not valid parameters in Powershell 2.0

Answer (score 23):

A cleaner approach:

```
Get-ChildItem "<name_of_directory>" | where {$_.Attributes -match'Directory'}
```

I wonder if PowerShell 3.0 has a switch that only returns directories; it seems like a logical thing to add.

Comment: FYI powershell 3.0 adds the `-Directory` and `-File` flags

Answer (score 12):

Use:

```
dir -r | where { $_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] }
```

Answer (score 7):

From PowerShell v2 and newer (k represents the folder you are beginning your search at):

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -attributes D -Recurse
```

If you just want folder names only, and nothing else, use this:

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Name -attributes D -Recurse
```

If you are looking for a specific folder, you could use the following. In this case, I am looking for a folder called `myFolder`:

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -attributes D -Recurse -include "myFolder"
```

Comment: And using PS 3.0 o 4.0 ?

Comment: The Attributes parameter doesn't seem to be in PS2, it gives an error "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Attributes'". It works ok in PS3.

Answer (score 6):

Less text is required with this approach:

```
ls -r | ? {$_.mode -match "d"}
```

Comment: This is the one that I'd use.

Comment: Even shorter: ls -r | ? { $_.mode -match "d" }

Comment: This doesn't find compressed folders

Comment: Because a compressed folder is a zip file

Comment: It is not always useful to recurse everything. You could have an extremely deep and bushy tree where you only are interested in directories exactly two levels down; searching thirty levels down is a waste of time.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer mentions

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object FullName
```

to get a "raw string".
But in fact objects of type `Selected.System.IO.DirectoryInfo` will be returned. For raw strings the following can be used:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | % { $_.FullName }
```

The difference matters if the value is concatenated to a string:

- with `Select-Object` suprisingly `foo\@{FullName=bar}`
- with the `ForEach`-operator the expected: `foo\bar`

Comment: Select-Object will actually return objects of type PSCustomObject.  While you can use % (which is ForEach-Object) to get the raw strings like you did, you can also use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName`

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
dir -Directory -Recurse | Select FullName
```

This will give you an output of the root structure with the folder name for directories only.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
Get-ChildItem \\myserver\myshare\myshare\ -Directory | Select-Object -Property name |  convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation  | Out-File c:\temp\mydirectorylist.csv
```

Which does the following

- Get a list of directories in the target location:
  `Get-ChildItem \\myserver\myshare\myshare\ -Directory`
- Extract only the name of the directories:
  `Select-Object -Property name`
- Convert the output to CSV format:
  `convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation`
- Save the result to a file:
  `Out-File c:\temp\mydirectorylist.csv`

Comment: It would be great if you can explain each step so that more people can see what is going on.

Comment: This won't work in Powershell 2.0 which was the specific need of the OP.  the -[/Dir/Directory] are not valid parameters in Powershell 2.0

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use **Get-ChildItem** to recursively get all folders and files first.  And then pipe that output into a **Where-Object** clause which only take the files.

```powershell
# one of several ways to identify a file is using GetType() which
# will return "FileInfo" or "DirectoryInfo"
$files = Get-ChildItem E:\ -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.GetType().Name -eq "FileInfo"} ;

foreach ($file in $files) {
  echo $file.FullName ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit more readable and simple approach could be achieved with the script below:

```
$Directory = "./"
Get-ChildItem $Directory -Recurse | % {
    if ($_.Attributes -eq "Directory") {
        Write-Host $_.FullName
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `$_.Attributes -eq "Directory"` will fail as soon as the Directory has any attribute other than `Directory` i.e. Hidden, System, ReadOnly etc. The right way to do it is `$_.Attributes.HasFlag([System.IO.FileAttributes]::Directory)`

Comment: `"Directory" -in $_.Attributes` would work as well.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is based on the TechNet article *[Fun Things You Can Do With the Get-ChildItem Cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692796.aspx)*.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\foo | Where-Object {$_.mode -match "d"}
```

I used it in my script, and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

This question is well and truly answered but thought I'd add something extra as I've just been looking at this.

`Get-ChildItem` happens to produce **two** types of objects whereas most commands produce just one.

**FileInfo** and **DirectoryInfo** are returned.

You can see this by viewing the 'members' available to this command like so:

```
Get-ChildItem | Get-Member
```

- TypeName: System.IO.DirectoryInfo
- TypeName: System.IO.FileInfo

You'll see the various methods and properties available to each type. Note that there are differences. For example that the **FileInfo** object has a **length** property but the DirectoryInfo object doesn't.

Anyway, technically, we can return just the directories by isolating the DirectoryInfo object

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.GetType().Name -eq "DirectoryInfo"}
```

Obviously as the top answer states the most straightforward solution is to simply use `Get-ChildItem -Directory` but we now know how to work with multple object types in future :)

Comment: This is probably not the easiest way, but it is a helpful insight, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path \\server\share\folder\ -Recurse -Force | where {$_.Attributes -like '*Directory*'} | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\Export.csv -Encoding "Unicode" -Delimiter ";"
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question specifically (using `IO.FileAttributes`):

```
Get-ChildItem c:\mypath -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Attributes -band [IO.FileAttributes]::Directory}
```

I do prefer Marek's solution though:

```
Where-Object { $_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the PsIsContainer Object

```
Get-ChildItem -path C:\mypath -Recurse | where {$_.PsIsContainer -eq $true}
```

Comment: Is this different from the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3085524/231929 (2010)?

Answer (score 0):

TRY THE FOLLOWING 
dir -Directory -Name

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use which gives you both the directory and the filename:

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\mypath" -Recurse |  ForEach-Object {
    $directory = Split-Path $$_.Fullname -parent
    Write-Host "directory = $directory"
    $file = Split-Path $$_.Fullname -leaf
    Write-Host "file = $file"
}
```