# Powershell issue.. running v2.0 on server, v3.0 on PC...script bugging out

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

i have the below script i need to run on a server running PS 2.0... i have tested it on my local machine PS 3.0 and it works fine.... however, when i run it on the server (2008 R2) i get an error on (`$folder in (Get-ChildItem  -Directory $sourceFolder)`) saying that  `-Directory` is unexpected... but only on the server.

Is there an issue with my script, or something else?

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope "CurrentUser" -ExecutionPolicy "Unrestricted"

$sourceFolder = "server1\a\b\c"
$destFolder   = "server2\a\b\c"

New-Item -Path "$destFolder\Log" -ItemType Directory | Out-Null

foreach ($folder in (Get-ChildItem  -Directory $sourceFolder)) {

    "robocopy `"$($sourceFolder)\$($folder)\zArchive\Data files to Nov 13`"     `"$($destFolder)\$($folder)\Data files to Nov 13`" /E /MOVE /DCOPY:T     /log+:`"$($destFolder)\Log\log.log`"" | Out-File zArchiveMove.txt -Append
    "robocopy `"$($sourceFolder)\$($folder)\Data files to Nov 13`"     `"$($destFolder)\$($folder)\Data files to Nov 13`" /E /MOVE /DCOPY:T     /log+:`"$($destFolder)\Log\log.log`"" | Out-File zArchiveMove2.txt -Append
}
```

Comment: I can't find any reference to it but using v2.0, it seems there's no `-directory` parameter. Using v4.0 there is so I assume that the parameter has been added in v3.0.

Comment: hmm ok... do you know what the v2.0 alternative for -Directory is???

Comment: You could use the answer from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085295/how-do-i-get-only-directories-using-get-childitem).

Answer (score 0):

There wasn't a directory parameter in V2.0. Back in those days (LOL) we used $PSIsContainer

```
foreach ($folder in (Get-ChildItem $sourceFolder | ? {$_.PSIsContainer}))
```

Comment: thanks Cole9350. im new to powershell so im still working may way through some of these kinds of things. :)

Answer (score 0):

Still having issues with powershell, and running out of time. I ended up using a batch file to complete the work which is a little shorter than the ps script. thought id share it if anyone finds it useful. :)

```
for /f "delims=|" %%s in ('dir /ad/b') do robocopy "\\server\source\%%s\folder1" "\\server2\dest\%%s\folder1" /E /MOVE
```