# powershell and windows explorer (properties) have different count results

Tags: powershell, count, properties, powershell-2.0, windows-explorer

I'm recursively counting total number of objects (files, folders, etc) to check folders vs their Amazon S3 backups.
When I use windows explorer on a folder (right click --> properties), I get a smaller number of total objects than what the following powershell code generates.  Why?
Amazon S3 matches the count from Windows Explorer 100% of the time.  Why is powershell giving a higher total number, and what is the likely difference (system files, hidden files, etc)?  The total number of objects in these folders is routinely 77,000+.

`folder_name; Get-ChildItem  -Recurse | Measure-Object | %{$_.count}`

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of files and folders in separate variables, you can do

```
# create two variables for the count
[int64]$totalFolders, [int64]$totalFiles = 0
# loop over the folders in the path
Get-ChildItem -Path 'ThePath' -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.PSIsContainer) { $totalFolders++ } else { $totalFiles++ }
}
# output the results
"Folders: $totalFolders`r`nFiles: $totalFiles"
```

The `-Force` switch makes sure also hidden and system files are counted.

A probably faster alternative is to use robocopy:

```
$roboCount    = robocopy 'ThePath' 'NoDestination' /L /E /BYTES
$totalFolders = @($roboCount -match 'New Dir').Count - 1   # the rootfolder is also counted
$totalFiles   = @($roboCount -match 'New File').Count
# output the results
"Folders: $totalFolders`r`nFiles: $totalFiles"
```

Comment: Thank you for `-Force` PowerShell was ignoring items flagged as hidden resulting in missed asset processing and asset counts.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to replicate.

When in file explorer, right-click the folder in question -> properties
Under the `General` tab, there's a section called `Contains`.
This lists both the Files and Folders as separate numbers.
In my example I have `19,267 Files, 1,163 Folders` which is a total of 20,430 objects

When I run

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\folder -Recurse | measure | % Count
```

it returns `20430`

When I run

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\folder -Recurse | ?{$_.PSiscontainer -eq $false} | measure | % count
```

it returns `19267`

When I run

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\folder -Recurse | ?{$_.PSiscontainer -eq $true} | measure | % count
```

it returns `1163`

Are you certain that you're counting both the files and folders when manually viewing the properties?

Answer (score 0):

The discrepancy comes from Windows Explorer counting files, and separately, folders.  Powershell (version 2.0 Build 6.1) is counting everything together.  It seems -File and -Directory don't work in PowerShell V2.0.

I really want to be able to get a list as a .cvs or .txt output of just the number of files (recursively) from a large number of folders.  Going through windows explorer is one by one, and I don't get this as an output that I can copy/paste.

Comment: Filter directories using [PSIsContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3085524/52598). Note that the linked answer only wants folders so invert the condition.